Error:Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate' in your configuration
I am trying to run my application but its giving me this error. It says I need to configure my SimpMessagingTemplate but when I tried @Autowire it still didn't work how can i solve this problem
configuration file
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ChatConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker( "/user");
    }
    
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverter) {
         DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        messageConverter.add(converter);
        return false;
    }
}

controller(UserController.java)
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChatController {
    
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private final ChatMessageService chatMessageService;

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    public void processMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        ChatMessage savedMsg = chatMessageService.save(chatMessage);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                chatMessage.getReceiver(), "/queue/messages",
                new ChatNotification(
                        savedMsg.getChatId(),
                        savedMsg.getSender(),
                        savedMsg.getReceiver(),
                        savedMsg.getMessage()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/messages/{senderId}/{recieverId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ChatMessage>> findChatMessages(@PathVariable String senderId,
            @PathVariable String recieverId) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(chatMessageService.findChatMessages(senderId, recieverId));
    }
}

(ChatController.java)
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChatController {
    
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private final ChatMessageService chatMessageService;

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    public void processMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        ChatMessage savedMsg = chatMessageService.save(chatMessage);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                chatMessage.getReceiver(), "/queue/messages",
                new ChatNotification(
                        savedMsg.getChatId(),
                        savedMsg.getSender(),
                        savedMsg.getReceiver(),
                        savedMsg.getMessage()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/messages/{senderId}/{recieverId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ChatMessage>> findChatMessages(@PathVariable String senderId,
            @PathVariable String recieverId) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(chatMessageService.findChatMessages(senderId, recieverId));
    }
}

pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


First,I tried autowiring it and is says cannot be injected something like that..
2.Second, I tried using @ComponentScan it still gave me an error


Adding @Autowired isn't configuring a SimpMessagingTemplate. You need to create an @Bean method for it.
